# Correlation along list of lists

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of lists named `L` were each element `L[[i]][[j]]` is a vector.
What I want to get is:

. . .  for each "initial list" `L[[i]]` a vector with the correlations like that:

```
(cor(L[[i]][[1]], L[[i]][[1]]) , cor(L[[i]][[1]], L[[i]][[2]]), . . ., cor(L[[i]][[1]], L[[i]][[10]]))
```

I tried it using the following code:

```
lapply(BRAY.dis, function(x) unlist(lapply(x, function(y) cor(y, y[[1]]))))
```

but I obtained following message :

```
 "Error in cor(y, y[[1]]) : incompatible dimensions"
```

## -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
# Example:
set.seed(123)

L <- list()
 for (i in 1:20){
  L[[i]] <- list()
 for (j in 1:10){
  L[[i]][[j]] <- runif(100)
}
```

}

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: Maybe, `lapply(L, function(l) cor(l[[1]], as.data.frame(l[-1]))`.

Comment: Thank you @Roland! How can I put the correct anwer such the people can see? Am i doing right writing an answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to @Roland 's suggestion, the solution to the problem I asked would be:

```
# Saving it into a list named R
  R <- lapply(L, function(l) as.vector(cor(l[[1]], as.data.frame(l))))
```

Comment: I'd actually use `vapply` (or `sapply` if you do this interactively).